# Use cisco catalyst to split 26er Subnet into 2 Networks?

Tags: networking, cisco, ip, routing

Is it possible to split a Network into 2 parts? Example there are a 192.168.100.129/26 Network i want to split one Address, the last one for example, to a diffrent vlan. So can i create IP based VLANs? Is it possible or i need a router for this function?

Something like

```
vlan1: 192.168.100.130 - 192.168.100.190 on port 1 & 2 
vlan2: 192.168.100.130 - 192.168.100.189 on port 1 
vlan3: 192.168.100.190 on port 2
```

Any suggestion?

Regards
Rene

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really split off the subnet like you're thinking without creating two new subnets of 192.168.100.128/27 and 192.168.100.160/27

What you may be looking for is an ACL on the ports?

Comment: I think i did not need vlan but a ACL that allow only Address 192.168.100.190 on Port 3, Port 1 deliver the IPs and Port 2 can access the wohle IP Range.

Comment: Yes, you need an ACL. Something like: allow 192.168.100.190, deny any.

Comment: So i access to Port 3 with "int fa0/3" but i can only set ip address and ip igmp is'nt ACL supported on Catalyst 2950?

Comment: The configuration guide for 2950 ACLs is available here: http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/switches/lan/catalyst2950/software/release/12.1_9_ea1/configuration/guide/swacl.html

Comment: thx. I setting up an ACL with number 101 but how can i assign this ACL to Port 3? I can't find anything in the Docu?!

Comment: within the interface configuration, you would type: ip access-group {access-list-number} in

Comment: there is no option ip access-group. Is it impossible to set Port ACL on Catalyst 2950?

Comment: from manpage: The ip access-group interface configuration command is only valid when applied to a management interface of a Layer 2 interface. ACLs cannot be applied to interface port-channels. What does this mean? A L2 Interface is a normal interface port on switch?!

Comment: i can't configure acl to L2 Port, only to vlan. Can i set on Interface to more than 1 Vlans? Then i can set the ACL for each group.

Answer (score 1):

You're misunderstanding VLAN's and subnetting.

A port can only belong to one VLAN unless it's a trunk port.

You can't assign the same ip address range to each VLAN. Well, you can but network communication won't operate properly as you won't be able to route traffic from one VLAN to another as they're all in the same subnet.

Comment: I have 3 Ports, one came from Router with 192.168.100.129/26 Addresses to Port1, on Port 2 there are a firewall they use Addresses .130-.189 and to Port3 there are only .190 Address. So i did not need a vlan but a restriction that Port 3 only Access with .190 Source-IP. It is possible?